# ¿Cual seria la mejor manera de comparar si dos objetos son de la misma clase? C#

Tags: c#

Me explico, estoy haciendo mis pinitos en C# y tengo una duda.
Tengo una Interfaz la cual tiene 4 metodos, y dos clases nuevas que heredan de esta interfaz. Lo que intento es que al llamar a uno de esos metodos "CompareTo()" dependiendo de si es un objeto u otro realizar tareas diferentes, el problema es que la clase padre es una interfaz y no puedo acceder al atributo de esta ya que no existe.

Intento seguir este ejemplo, herendando "IComparable";

```
class Persona : IComparable<Persona>
{
    public double Sueldo { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Persona p)
    {
        return this.Sueldo.CompareTo(p.Sueldo);
    }
}


class Ingeniero : Persona { .... }

class Programador : Persona { .... }
```

El problema es que mi clase padre es una interfaz, por lo tanto no puedo acceder al atributo, como ya he mencionado antes.
¿Cual seria la mejor manera de realizar esto? Es un ejercicio tonto, no es que intente realizarlo así por gusto :D, veo ejemplos en Java haciendo casting pero según me informo leyendo no es algo muy aconsejable.
Me gustaría conocer maneras "profesionales" sin chapuzas de por medio.

Muchas gracias

Comment: `.CompareTo()` es usado para poder hacer ordenamientos. Devuelve un `int` positivo si la instancia actual es mayor que la que pasa por parámetro, 0  si son iguales y negativo si es menor. No creo que eso sea lo que buscas. A que tareas te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Tienes una mala definición de POO, en el código que pones la **clase** `Persona` está **implementada** con la interfaz genérica `IComparable` y las clases `Ingeniero` y `Programador` **heredan** de la clase `Persona` (_Una clase no es una interfaz_). Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir de que manera estas comparando las instancias de tus clases.

Comment: ¿A que interfaz te refieres? Por favor agrega el código completo y sobre todo donde tratas de hacer esa comparación

Comment: Para que `Persona` sea una interfaz, debe estar declarada así: `interface Persona : IComparable<Persona> { ... }`. O en su caso, si la definición es `interface Persona { ... }`, las clases que hereden de `Persona` deberán de igual forma declaradas así: `class Ingeniero : Persona, IComparable<Persona> {... }`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Usando reflect se soluciona ese problema algo así

```
 if(p.GetType() == typeof(Ingeniero)){
     //Cast y Codigo para ingeniero
 }
```

En donde p es una instancia de tu interfaz

Comment: Esto esta lejos de ser la mejor forma. El mismo OP menciona que ya ha leido que no es aconsejable. Además que la pregunta no es clara.

Comment: @Carlos Muñoz que propones?  Tienes una instancia de una interfaz, como haces para validar que objeto la construyo

Comment: En primer lugar la terminología es incorrecta. Una interfaz no se puede instanciar. La instancia es de alguna clase que implemente la interfaz. Segundo para hacer lo que mencionas en tu respuesta mejor sería usar `if (p is Ingeniero ingeniero)` pero de todas maneras la pregunta no es clara. Lo mas probable es que la mejor respuesta tiene que ver con usar polimorfismo pero no se puede asegurar hasta no entender correctamente el problema

Comment: En ese orden de ideas, ponlo como respuesta, si es cierto que ya hiciste la observacion que la pregunta esta mal hecha, el caso es que en primera instancia, si se puede construir una instancia de una interfaz si la construyo  con un objeto que la implemente, segundo, si bien es cierto que hay cierta ambiguedad en la pregunta lo que si se entiende es que el necesita saber que tipo de objeto es la instancia de la interfaz para acceder a metodos particulares posiblemente con cast, y tres no conocia esa forma como lo hiciste, esta bien, la probare cuando pueda

Comment: @Lcop bueno, creo que hay una brecha muy grande entre que la pregunta sea mala y que no sea claro lo que se pregunta. Profesionalmente, no es adecuado caer en suposiciones, es por eso que se pide que las preguntas sean claras para poder tener el contexto exacto de lo que se pregunta, con esto, buscamos dar respuestas puntuales a problemas puntuales y tampoco no es nuestra intención "molestar" a otros usuarios, todo lo contrario, buscamos apoyarnos entre todos. Una vez que el OP aclare lo que realmente necesita podremos dar una respuesta acorde a sus necesidades :)